# Program fails to get a hold on to the output stream sometimes. Why is it so?

Tags: java

I have two programs , which are sitting on either side of a network socket . I have them make conversation with each other. One of them is a chat bot, which gives some responses, depending on what i enter as an input in  the other program . Most of the time it does work flawlessly. But sometimes , the chat bot keeps waiting and waiting and i don't get any reply back from it. This , however , happens very rarely. But does any one know, why it is happening ?  How can i get rid of this obvious bug ?

I do check for most of the exceptions here, i/o exceptions being the most predominant one. But i don't really get any exceptions. The program systems to hang around a thread , which i found out during debugging it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you don't swallow any exceptions. When something is wrong, the code will throw an exception telling you what is wrong (which hopefully gives you a clue how to fix it).

Comment: Thanks, Aaron. I do check for most of the exceptions here, i/o exceptions being the most predominant one. But i don't really get any exceptions. The program systems to hang around a thread , which i found out during debugging it .

Comment: @TheDarkKnight: I see. Any reason why you withhold such important information in your question?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. Missed it while constructing the Qs. Will edit to the original post right away .

Comment: Hey Aaron, Thanks a lot for your inputs . Finally, I got  a hold of the problem. The data , sometimes was not getting written to the socket, hence the bot was kept on waiting. Now after every write, i am using the flush() method. The thread that previously used to hang is not hanging now. And the programs as a whole are working without any hitch .